# How to populate a Select type input php from Json

Tags: php, json, zend-framework, combobox

I'm building a zend framework project and I'm using php for the first time so my apolagies in advance if the question is too dumb or if it was already answered but I didnt find it.

I'm trying to populate a select type input (dropdown list) with data that I get from an api.
The code I have on my Form class (extends Zend\Form\Form) is this:

```
    $url = 'http://localhost:63715/api/Local';

    $jsonData = file_get_contents($url);
    $jsonDataObject = json_decode($jsonData);

    $local = new Element\Select('local');
    $local->setLabel('Local');
    $local->setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
```

The json code I recieve from the API is this:

```
[{"ID": 1,"Name": "Local 1"},{"ID": 2,"Name": "Local 2"}]
```

I have no idea how to populate $local with the data I recieved, all I find on the internet is jquery and js.

Thanks.

Comment: try `json_decode()` your   json data, then you can use it   in php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://localhost:63715/api/Local';

$jsonData = file_get_contents($url);
$jsonDataArray = json_decode($jsonData,true);

$options=[];
foreach ($jsonDataArray as $data){
    $options[$data['ID']] = $data['Name'];
}

$local = new Element\Select('local');
$local->setLabel('Local');
$local->setAttribute('class', 'form-control'); 
$local->setAttribute('options',$options);
```

Comment: It works, but the object is populated with 'id' and 'local 1' and I want it to be populated with 'local1' and 'local 2'

Comment: I have made some edits. please try it. Thanks @Bruno

Answer (score 0):

ZF Style :

```
<?php

namespace YourNamespace;

use Zend\Form\Element\Select;
use Zend\Http\Client;
use Zend\Json\Json;

class YourJsonSelect extends Select
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getValueOptionsDefault()
    {
        $client = new Client('http://localhost:63715/api/Local');
        $response = $client->send();

        $array = Json::decode($response->getBody(), Json::TYPE_ARRAY);

        $options = [];
        foreach ($array as $data) {
            $options[$data['ID']] = $data['Name'];
        }
        return $options;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getValueOptions()
    {
        if (!$this->valueOptions) {
            $this->valueOptions = $this->getValueOptionsDefault();
        }
        return $this->valueOptions;
    }
}
```

---

```
// And "voilà"
$local = new YourNamespace\YourJsonSelect('local');
$local->setLabel('Local');
$local->setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
```